# mockito "verify" checks current state, but does not reset mock invocations

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using Mockito in my JUnit tests. The test is an integration test, testing a whole scenario, thus there are many assertions and `verify(mock)`s in it.

My problem is, that I'm writing some production code, doing some assertions and then verify the mock which works, until there is an identical mock invocation. see the simplified code:

```
interface I {
    void m1();
    void m2();
}

// some decorator
class T implements I {
    public T(I decorated) {
        /*...*/
    }

    /* ... */
}

public void testInvalid() {
    I m = mock(I.class);
    T t = new T(m);

    t.m1();
    assertEquals("m1", t.getLastMethod());
    verify(m).m1();

    t.m2();
    assertEquals("m2", t.getLastMethod());
    verify(m).m2();

    t.m1();
    assertEquals("m1", t.getLastMethod());
    verify(m).m1();

    // TooManyActualInvocations t.m1(): Wanted 1 time, but was 2 times ...
}

public void testValid() {
    I m = mock(I.class);
    T t = new T(m);

    t.m1();
    assertEquals("m1", t.getLastMethod());

    t.m2();
    assertEquals("m2", t.getLastMethod());

    t.m1();
    assertEquals("m1", t.getLastMethod());

    verify(m, times(2)).m1();
    verify(m).m2();
}
```

One idea is to verify the mocks at the end, but let's say there is a small stupid implementation mistake which leads to invoking the method m1 twice and m2 once but not as I would expect it in `testInvalid` but in the end the test would pass. I want my test to fail early. How do I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Thanks to @Woozy Coder:

Didn't mentioned, that `reset` would also be an option, but since it has to be called between verify and the next equal stub call, it makes it hard to write "nice" and correct tests, I think. There should be two different mocking styles:

1. "postcondition" mocking as Mockito does it
2. "early" mocking which would be an implicit reset after a verify-block

something like:

```
earlyReset(m).after(
    new Runnable() {
        t.someMethodInvokingTwoStubs();

        verify(m).someMethod1();
        verify(m).someMethod2();
    }
);
```

Comment: Give a try to this [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188299/is-this-an-appropriate-use-of-mockitos-reset-method)

Comment: Do not test multiple methods in one test method. A test should have ONE thing that it tests and preferably ONE thing which can fail. Testing multiple methods makes your test more complex. Separating your tests into multiple test methods will solve that problem.

Comment: @WoozyCoder thanks, edited my post

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz it's an integration test. It tests a finite state machine, respectively it was TDD because I wanted to write some production code which helped me designing it. All the components it uses are unit tested, but the state machine uses very much reflection and my test is a scenario with inner test classes and annotations.

Answer (score 4):

I am having a similar problem and decided to use `clearInvocations()` (arrived in Mockito 2.1)

https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#clearInvocations-T...-

Using `reset()` has the drawback that you loose your stubbing as well, `clearInvocations()` only  clears the invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito was written to avoid brittleness, such that verification can make the least-specific assertion possible to allow for implementations to evolve without changing the test. *If it doesn't matter to your test system that you're calling these methods multiple times, then you shouldn't ask Mockito to check it.*

Alternatives:

- Use `atLeast` or `atLeastOnce` to ensure the call happened at all without worrying how many *additional* times the method is called.
- If the call is stubbed to have return values, infer that the system works from state assertions about the data you've stubbed.
- If you really need stub or verification behavior to change across a single test method, your mock may grow outside the scope of what Mockito does well. Use an Answer for a single method, or write a manual Fake that simulates the interconnected methods properly.

Comment: I thought about implementing a ticket machine with my state machine. It starts in an IdleState which should invoke `onIdle`, then we choose a ticket, pay it and it should return to IdleState and invoke `onIdle` again. This is a quiet complex test, but it's the basis for the state machine's implementation, as well as functionality documentation. At the beginning I expect onIdle to be called and finally after ticket is paid. `atLeast(2)` at the end is too vague for me. I think that Mockito is not suitable for such integration tests, but I do like Mockito very much, because it's easy to use